# Python --> Asserting dictionary exists in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I'd like to check if it exists inside a list.
What would be the best way to assert it?

```
   tag_to_test_dict = {
    'category': 'environment',
    'name': 'quality assurance'
},{
    'category': 'department',
    'name': 'accounting'
}

gui_tags_list = [
    'department: accounting',
    'environment: quality assurance'
]
```

I tried this, as suggested, but it doesn't yield a good response:

```
    if all(name in tag_to_test_dict for name in gui_tags_list):
        return 'True'
```

^ Fixed a bit the data structures

Comment: What is your match criteria? The keys or the values?

Comment: I want to know that both the values in the dictionary are in the list

Answer (score 1):

> to know that both the values in the dictionary are in the list

The solution using `set` object:

```
has_all = set(tag_to_test_dict.values()) <= set(v for d in gui_tags_list for k,v in d.items())
print(has_all)
```

The output:

```
False
```

---

> *issubset(other)*
>   ***set <= other***
>
> Test whether every element in the **`set`** is in other.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set.issubset

Comment: Will this work with Python 2.7? My project is, unfortunately a 2.7 project

Comment: @new_to_coding, read the OP's comment: *I want to know that both the values in the dictionary are in the list*

Comment: Hmm this gets me False output although I kinda anticipated a True reply. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you wrote: *to know that both the values in the dictionary are in the list*. The approach returns `False` as it should, cause `environment` is not within values of the list of dicts. Otherwise, you should elaborate the rules of matching

Comment: Hmm I think I made a mistake there somewhere, I'll dig a bit and reformat the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, the way I actually solved it was:

```
for tag_to_test in tag_to_test_dict:
    assert '{}{} {}'.format(tag_to_test.values()[0], ":", tag_to_test.values()[1]) in gui_tags_list
```